# When does a project get too big for mysql

Tags: mysql, web-applications, project-management

I know google uses its own Big Tables (is that right?) and Facebook and Twitter use Cassandra but when does your everyday project outgrow mysql (if ever?)

If you were starting out on a potentially massive scale web application, would you use mysql as an engine or start with an alternative from the start?

Comment: I think facebook still uses mysql for it's data. Messages are in cassandra. I could be wrong though

Comment: you could be right, i think it uses cassandra for its "inbox", just trying to remember anything from The Social Network, ha!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only way you can know when MySQL isn't good enough is when you start to see performance issues or you feel like your fighting to keep it going. If you are aware that your application is potentially huge then you should be implementing the right tools from the start otherwise it's a huge headache transferring at a later date.

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple metric which will tell you the answer - it depends not only on the amount of data, number of transactions but also the nature of the replication - number of replicated sites, required speed of replication etc.

Yes, a large scale noSQL clsuter can out-perform a a MySQL cluster built for the same budget for OLTP, however its called noSQL for a reason - when you need to start doing somethng useful with the data, the relational model and SQL language make slicing and dicing the data much easier. OTOH, at some point OLAP then overtakes the relational model in terms of performance - but I think it would be rather difficult to use a datawarehouse for transaction processing.

So its quite possible that the functional requirements of an application will outgrow the capabilities of a noSQL database much faster than the perofrmance requriements would outgrow a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with an alternative (PostgreSQL), but not because of scaling issues, but because MySQL's support for transactions and referential integrity is worthless.

Comment: It seems that you're trying to start a flamewar. Do you want help with that? `</clippy>`

Comment: Not trying to flame here, but MySQL does have data integrity issues - MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys at all, and even InnoDB silently commits a transaction when a DDL statement occurs.